# How to force Enter key to trigger "submit" function without need to focus an input

Tags: reactjs, keypress, enter

I'm making an app in react-redux and I want a simple feature but that's starting to look tricky to implement.

:)

I want to be able to open my webapp (I land on my login screen) and just hit enter (the browser has already saved my user and password and they are filled in in the correct input fields) and have that "enter" keystroke tigger my login function without me needing to click anywhere first to focus something.

(On a non-root component)

I've already got my password input (the last one) bound to the enter key correctly.

So pressing enter when I have the password field focused works :

```
handleSubmit() {
    const { authenticate } = this.props;
    const { tusername, tpassword } = this.state;
    const credentials = {
        username: tusername,
        password: tpassword,
    };
    authenticate(credentials);
}

_handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        this.handleSubmit();
    }
};

render() {
        return (
            <div onKeyPress={this._handleKeyPress} >
                <Card id="signin">
                    <CardImg top width="100%" src={rubisLogo} alt="Rubis" />
                    <InputGroup>
                        <Input
                            placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur"
                            value={this.state.tusername}
                            onChange={this.updateUser}
                        />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <InputGroup>
                        <Input
                            placeholder="Mot de passe"
                            type="password"
                            value={this.state.tpassword}
                            onChange={this.updatePassword}
                            onKeyPress={this._handleKeyPress}
                        />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <div>
                    <Button
                    id="btn"
                    onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                    to="/home">Login
                    </Button>
                    </div>
                    <ModalPassword class="modal" buttonLabel="Mot de passe oublié ?" />
                    <ModalAccount class="modal" buttonLabel="Créer un compte" />
                </Card>
            </div>);
    }
```

as you can see I've tried putting it on the div but that didn't work. also I don't want a solution based on that. I want the enter-key to be a gobal fallback on this view. the user can't loose this funtionality just because he clicked somewhere.

Comment: this is really bugging me. still can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the focus to the div by default using tabIndex so that the javascript event will be triggered

```
render() {
        return (
            <div onKeyPress={this._handleKeyPress} tabIndex="1" >
                <Card id="signin">
            ..)}
```

Comment: : ( didn't work. I should clear this up: this isn't the root component I don't know if that's important. sounded like it would work. maybe the focus is automatically captured by something else aftewards? how can I know who has focus without trigering focus or de-focus?

Comment: but also a solution based on this would mean that I couldn't expect a use-case where the user selects a field then changes his mind and clicks empty space to deselect and then expects the enter key to work, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your components with a form tag instead of a div, handle the `onSubmit` event, and the property type of Login button you must set it to `submit`.

```
...
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent browser behavior
  // Handle submit logic
  ...
};

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      ...
      <Button
        id="btn"
        type="submit"
        to="/home">Login
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: app-ae732.js:27890 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
    at SignIn._this.handleSubmit (app-ae732.js:27890)
    at SignIn._this.handleKeyPress (app-ae732.js:27905)
    at Object.../node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (ReactErrorUtils.js:70)

Comment: Take a look https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: And ensure you got rid of the "key press" related code

Comment: I did a combination of your code sand @StateLess 's `tabIndex="1"` on the form and that still didn't work. I'm pretty convinced React messes with the focus